# JS: Can't remove eventListener for my debounce function

Tags: javascript

```
 let header = document.getElementById('header');

function logTitle() {
    console.log("Logging Title")
}

let debounceFunc = function debounce(fn, delay) {
    let newFn;

    return function(...args) {
       if (newFn) {
          clearTimeout(newFn);
       }
       newFn = setTimeout(() => {
           fn(...args)
       },delay);
 
    }
}


header.addEventListener('click', debounceFunc(logTitle, 3000));
```

Tested this and works as expected.  Then when I try to remove it is when I have trouble:

```
header.removeEventListener('click', debounceFunc);
```

I also tried `header.removeEventListener('click', debounceFunc, true)` and `header.removeEventListener('click', debounceFunc, false);` but neither are removing it.

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

EDIT: I also tried originally creating the debounce without setting it to a variable like this and just attached `debounce` to the clickEvent but that didn't work when removing either:

```
// tried creating function like this as well: 
function debounce(fn, delay) {
    let newFn;

    return function(...args) {
       if (newFn) {
          clearTimeout(newFn);
       }
       newFn = setTimeout(() => {
           fn(...args)
       },delay);
 
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is the removing of the event listener done?

Comment: @FarazShaikh I am doing this all in browser console so I am executing the removal of the event listener, testing it by clicking on the element in the DOM and it's not working

Comment: I think the issue is that `debounceFunc`, when evaluated by `addEventListner`, returns an anonymous function, that is the function that is added to the eventListener and not `debounceFunc`. You have to store a reference to that anonymous function then you can use that reference in `removeEvenrListner`

Comment: @FarazShaikh but isn't `debounceFunc` ultimately the function attached to eventListener and removing that should remove everything within, right?

Comment: No you are not passing in a reference to the `debounceFunc`, you are calling `denounceFunc`, which evaluates it first then attaches the function returned from it. Once you put `()` after a function name it becomes a function call

Comment: @FarazShaikh you were right, thank you

Comment: Upvotes would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is trying to `removeEventListener` when listener is anonymous function. It's impossible. However, you can assign return value of `debounceFunc` to a variable, for example `my_callback`. After that, `my_callback` becomes a function. Then just pass `my_callback` to add/remove EventListener.

Just use this:

```
let header = document.getElementById('header');

function logTitle() {
    console.log("Logging Title")
}

let debounceFunc = function debounce(fn, delay) {
    let newFn;

    return function(...args) {
       if (newFn) {
          clearTimeout(newFn);
       }
       newFn = setTimeout(() => {
           fn(...args)
       },delay);
 
    }
}

let my_callback = debounceFunc(logTitle, 3000);

header.addEventListener('click', my_callback);
```

And then remove with this function call:

```
header.removeEventListener('click', my_callback);
```

Comment: Answer contains no explanation (I'm not the downvoter)

Comment: @Vlad `let debounceFunc = function debounce(fn, delay) { }` is still considered an anonymous function although the function is named?

Comment: @LegoGeo no, anonymous function is unnamed function. In you code, it's declared on line `return function(...args) {`

Comment: By the way, you can use `let debounceFunc = function (fn, delay) {` too, assigning anonymous function to the variable `debounceFunc`

Comment: thanks...so is this a good way to think about it:  the way I had it is where it was calling a new function each time so there is no way to remove that --the solution is to store it in a variable so that it can removed/referenced at a later date?

Comment: @LegoGeo The only difference between you old code and this code is storing return value of `debounceFunc`. So the function wasn't generated every time, you just couldn't access such function

Comment: that just made it click in my head, thanks so much

Answer (score 2):

You should save handle for event listener and unbind event listener by handle.
Like this:

```js
let header = document.getElementById('header');

function logTitle() {
    console.log("Logging Title")
}

let debounceFunc = function debounce(fn, delay) {
    let newFn;

    return function(...args) {
       if (newFn) {
          clearTimeout(newFn);
       }
       newFn = setTimeout(() => {
           fn(...args)
       },delay);
 
    }
}

const eventHandler = debounceFunc(logTitle, 300);

header.addEventListener('click', eventHandler);

document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', () => {
  header.removeEventListener('click', eventHandler);
})
```

```html
<header id="header">
I'm header, click me to debounce function
</header>
<button>
Click me to unbind event handler for header
</button>
```

Comment: that works, thank you but now I'm confused why ...why does that work when I set a variable to be the debounceFunc ( `const eventHandler = debounceFunc(logTitle, 300);` ) like that?